# App is crashing after capture image/scan QR code in android 12

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera, cordova-plugins, android-12

In my app user can capture images and scan QR code. App is working fine in all android versions expect android 12. App is crashing after capture image or scan QR code.

Code,

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            java.io.File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
                android.widget.Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Error occure while creating image file",
                        android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, android.net.Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_RESULT);
            }
        }
```

logs are here,

```
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3001, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.xxxxx/com.xxxx.xxxxx}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'org.apache.cordova.PluginManager org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.pluginManager' on a null object reference in method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)'

    android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5567)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4953)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:60)
    android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2374)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)**
```

I did't find any solution and please guide me to find proper solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey. Please post your code for starting Activity for result.

Comment: @OlegSkidan Added code please check

Comment: You can go to camera activity, make a photo, but after that you get a crash am I right?

Comment: @OlegSkidan yes exactly same as QR code scan but issue is happening only in android 12 devices

Comment: Are you using Apache Cordova?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I'm using Cordova. I have created custom cordova plugin and Activity to opening camera. JS -->Custom cordova plugin --> Activity --> Camera App(In build app).